# Rings in which every ideal contains a minimal ideal

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals, artinian

For a commutative  *Artinian* unital ring, it is well known that every ideal contains at least a minimal ideal, a non-zero ideal that dose not contain a proper non-zero ideal. In general, not *Artinian* case, are rings with above property important or are they a famous class of rings, or are there any characterization or description for them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If every nonzero right ideal of a ring $R$ contains a minimal right ideal, you usually express this by saying that **$R$ has an essential right socle.**

This expression is frequently used in the literature: try for example [this query](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22essential+right+socle%22) in google books.

I am not aware of alternative characterizations of this, although it is used in conjunction with other conditions to make characterizations. I think I saw it frequently used in Faith's work on pseudo-Frobenius and finitely-pseudo-Frobenius rings.

Answer (score 2):

If $A$ is a noetherian commutative domain and is not a field, then $A$ has no  minimal non-zero ideal at all.
**Proof**
Let $\mathfrak a$ be a minimal ideal. We have $\mathfrak a^2=\mathfrak a$ and thus by [NAKAYAMA](https://mathoverflow.net/a/61478/450)  there exists $e\in \mathfrak a$ with $a=ea$ for all $a\in \mathfrak a$. But then $e=e^2$, hence $e=0$ or $e=1$ so that $\mathfrak a=0$ or $\mathfrak a=A$.

**Geometric interpretation**
Given an integral noetherian affine scheme $X$,  no closed subscheme $\emptyset \subsetneq Y\subsetneq X$ is maximal .

Comment: Or positively formulated: Every noetherian commutative domain which has a minimal ideal is a field.

Comment: Seems a bit overkill! If $aR=(aR)^2$, then $a=aras$ for some $r,s\in R$, and cancelling you get $1=ras$ and $a$ is a unit. So a (possibly noncommutative, possibly nonNoetherian) domain with a minimal ideal is a division ring. I understand the additional hypotheses might be necessary for the geometric interpretation, but Nakayama is certainly not necessary for the proof :)

Comment: I don't think any justification is necessary, and I found it to be really interesting! I just didn't want anyone to get a false impression about the conditions or difficulty of proving this phenomenon.

Comment: Dear @schwieb: I agree that your calculation is more elementary and thus more satisfying. I'm just so used to Nakayama that I hadn't thought about doing an explicit calculation...